# CSS list-style and text-decoration having no effect

Tags: html, css

This is driving me bonkers. This incredibly simple thing is just not working and I have no idea what I'm missing.  The list-style: none and text-decoration: none are having absolutely no effect on the final product run in the browser.  The list still has bullets and the links are still underlined. Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Porshe</title>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">     </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo"/>
    </header>
    <nav id="nav1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/cars.html">Our Cars</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/staff.html">Our Staff</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/accessories.html">Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/locs.html">Our Locations</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/sales.html">Sales Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="content/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>


    </section>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
article, aside, figure, footer, header, nav, section {
display: block;

}
html{
    background-image: url(../images/gradient_gray-silver1.jpg)

}
body {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;

}
header img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

nav {
    float: left;
}

#nav1 ul{
    list-style: none;
}
#nav1 li a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;

}
```

Comment: Should probably remove question since you've just missed a closing bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/89zowwv5/)

You missed `}` for `header img` in your CSS

```
header img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing brace after

```
header img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/0j8qyyuz/)